# Unable to upload apk or .aab file in internal app sharing. Showing An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (6674F052)

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console, internal-app-sharing

I am really stuck with the internal app sharing feature of Google play console.
As I open the page for the uploading the file, It prompts the error message,"An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (6674F052)"

There's a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

As I try to upload my .apk file or .aab file, It just loads and loads and loads for decades.
I have to publish my app of play store hence I have to test my new In - app update feature through Internal app sharing.
I am trying over 24 hours now then.
I am really frustated because of this.

Please Help.
I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: I've been struggling with the same problem. I think that it's general issue. https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/mdnp1p/internal_app_sharing_bug/

Comment: I have asked the google team for it reported the issue. Let's see what google takes action

Comment: Its working now